# What is the translation for: "for those I love I will sacrifice"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

How can I translate "for those I love I will sacrifice" to Latin?
I got several different answers from different sources:

- prō meīs nihil nōn patiar
- prō dīlēctīs nihil nōn patiar
- Iillis quos amo deserviam

Answer (score 2):

Here are what those sentences literally mean:

> *prō meīs nihil nōn patiar*

"For the sake of mine and my own, there's nothing I won't endure."

> *prō dīlēctīs nihil nōn patiar*

"For the sake of the beloved ones [i.e. the ones I love], there's nothing I won't endure"

> *Iillis quos amo deserviam*

"I will be utterly devoted to the people whom I love."

Out of the three, I like the first one best. It's elegantly-put and has a very nice rhythm to it; I certainly couldn't do better than that myself.

Comment: I think the verb here is not *servare* but *servire*, "to serve" or "to be slave". The one to be served is often put in dative. A more devoted variant of the verb is *deservire*. Therefore the third suggestion is closer to "I will serve with devotion the ones I love" and is grammatical apart from the extraneous *i* in the first word.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Good call—do you want to write that in as an answer? Otherwise I'll edit mine.

Comment: Go ahead and put it in! If I come up with a nice idea for the phrasing of the whole sentence I might write a new answer, but that shouldn't keep you from improving yours.